# How to Get Data From Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-maps, firebase-dynamic-links

I have Make Google Map Integration Of My Application. Then Implement the firebase dynamic link when user and driver both location driection show on map then share the dynamic url and just click show in app also get data in log in string format. how to get string format data access from one variable which i store in project

Comment: AsAp Please Guide Me

Answer (score 0):

Add an intent filter for deep links

As with plain deep links, you must add a new intent filter to the activity that handles deep links for your app. The intent filter should catch deep links of your domain, since the Dynamic Link will redirect to your domain if your app is installed. This is required for your app to receive the Dynamic Link data after it is installed/updated from the Play Store and one taps on Continue button. In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

When users open a Dynamic Link with a deep link to the scheme and host you specify, your app will start the activity with this intent filter to handle the link.

JAVA IMPLEMENTATION.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
        .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                Uri deepLink = null;
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                }


                // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                // account.
                // ...

                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
            }
        });
```

KOTLIN IMPLEMENTATION

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks
    .getDynamicLink(intent)
    .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData: PendingDynamicLinkData? ->
        // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
        var deepLink: Uri? = null
        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
        }

        // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
        // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
        // account.
        // ...

    }
    .addOnFailureListener(this) { e -> Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e) }
```

Comment: Thanks but i have done this thing also store data from dynamic url in a string format but how to extract ?

Comment: I am trying to implement using Kotlin, but I am not getting Firebase.dynamicLinks